# Priority in display property, when two display properties are given in the same div

Tags: html, css

This is my div tag.

```
<div class="@Html.Raw(ViewBag.TabClass)
```

In tabclass, i am appending two others css classes. One class contains `display:none`, and the other class contains `display: inline`.

I need both classes to be there and the `display:hidden` should be applied to the whole div.

will that be possible ?

Comment: yes, see *selector specifity/wheight* https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ if same specifity/wheight, last one overwrite previous ones

Comment: Your div tag appears to need a closing double quote character and a right angle bracket ( "> ).

Comment: I have just given a section of my code. i do have added "> at the end.

Answer (score -1):

Add `!important` at css display.

**example:**

```
display:none !important;
```

Comment: I tried like you suggested. But it didn't work. The problem i am facing is, since there are two classes. display:inline is there in one class and display:none is there in another class. But when i comment out display:inline in that class, the functionality is working as expected, because it's taking display:hidden. But i cannot remove display:inline from that class, since it's being used in many other parts of the code. Is there any way to completely override the display:inline with display:none